# Why is the last value wrong?

Tags: java, binary, bit

Here is my methods :
Fl_IN = 1114599018 and k = 0

```
public void int FL(int FL_IN, int k) {
    int d0, d1;
    d0 = FL_IN >> 16;
    d1 = FL_IN & 0xffff;
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[k / 2]);
        d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[(k / 2 + 6) % 8 + 8]);
    } else {
        d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[((k - 1) / 2 + 2) % 8 + 8]);
        d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[((k - 1) / 2 + 4) % 8]);
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(d0));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(d1));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(d0 << 16));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((d0 << 16) | d1));
    System.out.println((d0 << 16) | d1);
}
```

And here is the output :

```
1110110010101000
10111001000110
11101100101010000000000000000000
11101100101010000010111001000110
-324522426
```

I don't understand why it is  saying that 11101100101010000010111001000110 = -324522426 it should be 3970444870

EDIT : Using long instead of int resolved the problem

Comment: Does it fit into a signed integer? See http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?hexadecimal=ECA82E46

Comment: An `int` is a 32-bit **signed** number. The value `3970444870` is too large to fit in 32-bit, signed `int`. The binary value `11101100101010000010111001000110` is equal to `-324522426` in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: This is because `d0` is a *signed* integer. See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for a very detailed article. If you want it print 3970444870, you must use a larger (64 bit) integer type, e.g. `long`.

Comment: Not knowing your input (I could deduct it but I won't), I'm gonna guess the value `(d0 << 16) | d1)` does not fit into the `INTEGER.MAX` value, hence it overflows and starts at the negative counterpart and starts adding again. Hence the "weird" number. The first 4 prints are of type `String` so there's virtuelly no limit to the size it can take

Comment: Oh god, yes I know what is a signed Integer but I don't see how I could deal with this problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integer ranges from `-2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647`  this value exceeds range 3,970,444,870.

Comment: If I use a float I can't use ">>" and "<<" operators. Is there any kind of way do dealt with it ?

Comment: why float? use long.